# "Template not found: dashboard" error on setup

Tags: installation, setup

When setting up Craft CMS I get a 404 error page that says

```
HTTP 404 - Not Found - yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Template not found: dashboard
```

I am running MAMP (PHP 7.2.8 and MySql 5.7.23) on a Mac and followed the installation instructions (using Composer) found on https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html.

Everything seems to run smoothly until I hit the "Web Browser Setup" part (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-6-run-the-setup-wizard), which is where I get the 404 page instead of the setup wizard.

Any clues to what could have gone wrong?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

I misread the installation instructions and thought I had to do BOTH the terminal setup and the web browser setup.

Comment: I had the same issue, kinda confusing documentation makes it seems like both are a step.